# Instalación del programa Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio

Me sale esta ventana con este error cuando abro el programa por primera vez, no sé a qué se debe en otra laptop he instalado el programa normal pero en la mía no se puede.

```
Error in nchar(homeDir) : invalid multibyte string, element 1
cuando cierro la ventana el rstudio se queda abierto pero no se puede trabajar sale lo siguiente
Warning message:
In normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) : path[1]="C:/Users/Zara�/OneDrive/Documentos": El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada
Warning message:
In normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) : path[1]="C:/Users/Zara�/OneDrive/Documentos": El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada
Warning message:
In normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) : path[1]="C:/Users/Zara�/OneDrive/Documentos": El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada
Warning message:
In normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) : path[1]="C:/Users/Zara�/OneDrive/Documentos": El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada
```

Comment: Bienvenido/a a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 0):

Tal como se indica [aquí](https://community.rstudio.com/t/hello-there-im-having-a-error-message-that-i-cant-understand/137805/5), Rstudio requiere que la carpeta `home` del usuario respete una codificación ascii estándar. En tu caso, entiendo que tu usuario tiene una `í` acentuada lo que estaría provocando estos errores.

Solución: crearte un nuevo usuario o eventualmente renombrar la carpeta `home` del mismo ([ver](https://superuser.com/questions/890812/how-to-rename-the-user-folder-in-windows-10))